# Upgrading default Ruby install on Mac

Tags: ruby, react-native, macos

Most of the examples I've seen here are for rvm or brew.  It looks like Ruby was preinstalled (not sure which package manager would be responsible).  Another words, it's not installed either by brew or rvm.

```
Location: /usr/bin/ruby
OS Version: 13.4
Current Ruby version: 2.6.3
Need: 2.7.0
```

Is there a way to upgrade this default version?  I fear by installing ruby through some other means I will create conflicts.

Comment: It is not recommended to upgrade (or even use) the default Rube version on MacOS, because it is under Apple‘s control. Other apps might depend on this specific version or Apple might update or even remove it with a future MacOS version.

Comment: So then it's about brew or rvm.  Which one do you recommend?  Basically I'm trying to do react native, which is requiring ruby 2.7.  I could install this directly in my react native project but then would have to do this continually for each new project.  I just want to be able to install Ruby 2.7 without infringing on the default Ruby install.  I see a lot of debate about brew vs rvm.

Comment: You might also want to check out rbenv and chruby.

Comment: I would use brew, because it allows installing only one Ruby version at a time. A version manager allows installing multiple Ruby versions at the same time, which is helpful when upgrading apps from one version to another or when working with multiple applications at the same time. I recommend looking into rbenv, rvm, asdf or chruby.

Answer (score 4):

***tl;dr summary***: Do *not* use system Ruby. Ever.

You are asking how to overwrite parts of the system Ruby installation. [*Do not do that*](https://moncefbelyamani.com/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby-to-install-gems-on-a-mac/). The system Ruby installation, provided by Apple, is for *use by the system itself* and for "legacy software". [It is *not* to be used by the user](https://dontusesystemruby.com/).

See [this official statement by Apple as part of the release notes for macOS Catalina](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-catalina-10_15-release-notes#Scripting-Language-Runtimes):

> Scripting language runtimes such as Python, Ruby, and Perl are included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. Future versions of macOS won’t include scripting language runtimes by default, and might require you to install additional packages. If your software depends on scripting languages, it’s recommended that you bundle the runtime within the app.

Even worse, a RubyGem can run arbitrary code during its installation process. If you install a RubyGem using `sudo`, which you would have to do in order to overwrite system Ruby, [you allow that Gem to run arbitrary code on your computer with full administrative privileges](https://moncefbelyamani.com/why-you-should-never-use-sudo-to-install-ruby-gems/).

So, what is the correct thing to do?

The correct thing to do is to install your own Ruby into a directory that you have access to and use that installation instead of the system one.

There are many different ways to do this. Personally, I use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) as a package manager. But I don't use the [ruby formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ruby) directly, instead, I use the [rbenv formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rbenv) to install [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to manage my Ruby installations and the [ruby-install formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ruby-install) to install [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install) for installing Ruby implementations.

Then, I can just use `rbenv install` to install a particular version of a particular Ruby implementation, `rbenv global` to set the version I want to use by default and `gem install` to install RubyGems for this particular version.

But, that's just one way to do it. You can install Ruby using Homebrew, [MacPorts](https://macports.org/), or [Fink](https://finkproject.org/). You can [compile Ruby yourself](https://ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#building-from-source). You can use ruby-install or [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build). You can use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/). You can install any of those manually or through Homebrew, MacPorts, or Fink.

It's up to you and your requirements. These are not all the same. For example, ruby-install and ruby-build are for *installing* Ruby. [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) and rbenv are for *switching between multiple Ruby installations*. RVM does both of those things. rbenv can do installation as well if ruby-install is installed. asdf can install and switch between multiple implementations of multiple programming languages, i.e., it can do what RVM does, but not just for Ruby; it also supports Erlang, Python, PHP, Swift, SML/NJ, Chez Scheme, SBCL, Zig, Raku, Scala, Rust, LFE, Perl, Java, PowerShell, .NET, Elixir, Lua, PureScript, Elm, D, Lean, Crystal, Kotlin, Haskell, Logtalk, Groovy, OCaml, Mercury, Go, Nim, Haxe, Idris, Io, Julia, and many many more.

Answer (score -3):

React-native uses a ruby gem for CocoaPods.

I have gotten this working by downgrading my react-native project to 0.69.0.  I am now able to view it in a real device.

This is what I did:

1. Create a new react-native project with version 0.69.

   ```
   npx react-native@0.69.0 init AwesomeProject2 --version 0.69.0
   ```
2. Pull up the workspace, not project, in Xcode.
3. Select Pods
4. Go to Build Settings
5. To the left in Targets select React-CodeGen
6. To the right select iOS Deployment Target: iOS 12.4
7. Run on device

   ```
    npx react-native run-ios --device
   ```

Comment: Why on earth would anyone give someone a -2 for posting a correct answer?